Socket.IO: Clients Not Receiving changeRoom Event in Multiplayer Game
I'm building a multiplayer game using Flutter for the frontend and Node.js with Socket.IO for the backend. The problem is that when a second player joins a room, the changeRoom event is not being received by the clients, even though both clients successfully connect to the server. The second player does receive the getPlayers event, but neither player receives the changeRoom event.
Problem Summary
i have two devices: Device1 and Device2.
Device1 creates a room and moves to the waiting lobby.
Device2 joins the same room and moves to the game screen.
Device1 remains in the waiting lobby and does not receive updates.
I have implemented Socket.IO event listeners on the client-side in Flutter to handle room updates and player updates. When a room is created by the first player, it navigates to a waiting lobby screen. When the second player joins the same room, the server emits three events: joinRoomSuccess, getPlayers, and changeRoom.
Here is my client-side code to listen for these events:
void joinRoomsuceessListener(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    _socketClient.on('joinRoomSuccess', (room) {
      ref.read(roomProvider.notifier).updateRoomData(room);
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, GameScreen.routeName);
    });
  }

  void changeRoomDataListener(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    _socketClient.on("changeRoom", (room) {
      print("event : changeRoom");
      ref.read(roomProvider.notifier).updateRoomData(room);
    });
  }

  void getPlayersDataListener(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    _socketClient.on("getPlayers", (players) {
      print("event : getPlayers");
      ref.read(roomProvider.notifier).updatePlayer1(players[0]);
      ref.read(roomProvider.notifier).updatePlayer2(players[1]);
    });
  }

These listeners are initialized in the initState method of my GameScreen widget:
class GameScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  static String routeName = '/gameScreen';
  const GameScreen({super.key});

  @override
  _GameScreenState createState() => _GameScreenState();
}

class _GameScreenState extends ConsumerState<GameScreen> {
  final SocketMethods _socketMethods = SocketMethods();
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _socketMethods.changeRoomDataListener(context, ref);
    _socketMethods.getPlayersDataListener(context, ref);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final roomNotifier = ref.read(roomProvider.notifier);
    final roomData = ref.watch(roomProvider);

    // isJoin true = wait
    // false = no wait
    return Scaffold(
      body: roomData['isJoin']
          ? WaitingLobby(id: roomData['_id'])
          : Center(
              child: Text(
                roomData.toString(),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}

here is the my server side code :


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("A user connected with socket id :", socket.id);
   
    socket.on('createRoom', async ({ nickname }) => {

        try {

            // create room
            let room = new Room();

            // we define the player who crete this room
            let player = {
                socketId: socket.id,
                nickname,
                playerType: "X",
            };
            room.players.push(player);
            room.turn = player;

            // save current version of room in mongodb
            room = await room.save();

            // get roomId 
            const roomId = room._id;
            console.log("Room created is : " + room);

            socket.join(roomId);

            // io : send data to everyone
            // socket : sending data to yourself or client

            io.to(roomId).emit("createRoomSuccess", room);

        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error during creating room" + error);
        }


    });

    socket.on('joinRoom', async (data) => {
        try {
            const nickname = data['nickname'];
            const roomId = data['roomId'];

            // print statement
            console.log(nickname);
            console.log(roomId);

            if (!roomId.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
                socket.emit("errorOccur", "Please enter a valid room ID.");
                return;
            }


            // find the room
            let room = await Room.findById(roomId);

            // room validation
            if (!room) {
                console.log("room not find");
                socket.emit('errorOccur', "room is not exist");
                return;
            }
            console.log("room is finded : ");
            console.log(room);

            // if room exist, then make sure that there is occupancy
            if (!room.isJoin) {

                socket.emit('errorOccur', "room is fulled");
                return;
            }


            if (room.isJoin) {

                // create player 
                let player = {
                    socketId: socket.id,
                    nickname,
                    playerType: "O",
                };

                // add player into room
                room.players.push(player);
                room.isJoin = false;
                console.log("added player and isJoin is false");
                // update the room
                room = await room.save();

                socket.join(roomId);

                console.log("room is saved");


                // send response

                console.log("emitting joinRoomSuccess");
                io.to(roomId).emit("joinRoomSuccess", room);

                console.log("emitting changeRoom");
                io.to(roomId).emit('changeRoom', room);

                console.log("emitting getPlayers");
                io.to(roomId).emit("getPlayers", room.players);

            } else {
                socket.emit(
                    "errorOccur",
                    "The game is in progress, try again later."
                );
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error during joining the room" + error);
        }


    });
});

this is my console log for device 1 :
connected to server
current state : {}
updated state : {occupancy: 2, maxRound: 6, currentRound: 1, isJoin: true, turnIndex: 0, _id: 66875a28e8980bc4e4ddd684, players: [{nickname: Harsh, socketId: f-Hwmz_8QQi4XxAOAAAB, points: 0, playerType: X, _id: 66875a28e8980bc4e4ddd685}], turn: {nickname: Harsh, socketId: f-Hwmz_8QQi4XxAOAAAB, points: 0, playerType: X, _id: 66875a28e8980bc4e4ddd686}, __v: 0}
waiting lobby building
Logs from Second Device:
connected to server
current state : {}
updated state : {_id: 66875a28e8980bc4e4ddd684, occupancy: 2, maxRound: 6, currentRound: 1, isJoin: false, turnIndex: 0, players: [{nickname: Harsh, socketId: f-Hwmz_8QQi4XxAOAAAB, points: 0, playerType: X, _id: 66875a28e8980bc4e4ddd685}, {nickname: Mihir, socketId: 2n9O6O-79m0pwt7WAAAD, points: 0, playerType: O, _id: 66875a28e8980bc4e4ddd686}], turn: {nickname: Harsh, socketId: f-Hwmz_8QQi4XxAOAAAB, points: 0, playerType: X, _id: 66875a28e8980bc4e4ddd686}, __v: 1}
event : getPlayers
please refer this whole source code link :
https://github.com/harsh522004/RealTimeTicTacToe

Is not the problem this part if (!room.isJoin) {? Here you only emits an error and is this code really correct, I mean more than one user should be able to join the same room right? Looking at the code it only seems like a single player can join a specific room?
